# Problem updating Register on BD with Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm starting with Electron JS and I have a little problem.

I am reading information from a database and copying it to another remote one. I connect well with both databases and insert the records without problem (As seen in the example) but now I want a field to be updated after copying the records to know that it has been copied.

I have tried the following way and the program runs but does not sync. Can you help me? Thank you.

```
ipcRenderer.on('sync_articulo', (event, results) => {
   const list = results
   list.forEach(element => {
      //
      //
      //ESTE CODIGO ES EL QUE INSERTA LOS REGISTROS 
      //
      //
         const objetoadd = {
                  IdArticulo:element.IdArticulo,
                  Descripcion:element.Descripcion,
                  Descripcion1:element.Descripcion1,
        }

        function addProductff(objetoadd)
        {
            const sql = "INSERT INTO sync_articulo SET ?";  
            dbr.query(sql, objetoadd, (error, results, fields) => {
            if(error) {
                  console.log(error);
            }
         });

        //Code to Update

        function updateproductff(objetoedit) 
         {
            let idElemento = objetoedit.IdArticulo;
            let wm_export = 1;
            const sql = "UPDATE sync_articulo SET wm_export=? WHERE id=?";  
            db.query(sql, [wm_export, id], (error, results, fields) => {
            if(error) {
               console.log(error);
            }
            });

         }   

         addProductff(objetoadd);
         updateproductff(objetoadd);

}
```

Comment: Please read up on [asynchronous JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous) – you'll need to call the second function from the callback function of the first query, but only if there wasn't an error.